# add styles to iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm wanting to update an iframe with css in javascript. I know how to update the iframe body with the code below but is there a way to insert css into the head of the iframe?

Thanks David

```
var previewFrame = document.getElementById('previewFrame');
var preview = previewFrame.contentDocument || previewFrame.contentWindow.document;

preview.open();
preview.write('New Content');
preview.close();
```

Comment: That's an awful way to update the content of an iframe, and it does "update" the `head` as well (by wiping it out).

Comment: @Teenu perhaps you can share how to do it the correct way?

Comment: You know the `src` attribute? DOM manipulation methods?

Comment: How will the src attribute of an iframe help add css styles.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think if you have iframe page under the same domain you should try this:

```
$("iframe").contents().find('head').append('<style type="text/css">' +'MY CSS IS HERE' + '</style>')
```

Comment: jquery? user asked for js

Comment: @Phlume Sorry, didn't see that...so,did I get downvote for that? Did you ask OP if he knows jquery or not?

Comment: @user3830694 why should Phlume ask it, when it was your assumption?

Comment: I saw that it was a duplicate, and that @user3830694 posted jquery, I commented on both, and then moved on.

Comment: @Phlume sorry...my apologies.